# Why do my functions crash the programme?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct packets
{
int source, destination, type, port;
char data[50];
};

int addpacket(int *, struct packets *);
void listpackets(int , struct packets *); 
void save(int, struct packets *);

int main()
{

struct packets *info;
char choice;
int records = 0;

info = malloc(sizeof(struct packets));

 do
 {
     puts("\n1. Add Packets\n");                //Menu with list of options.
     puts("\n2. List all saved packets\n");
     puts("\n3. Save packets\n");
     puts("\n4. Clear all packet information\n");
     puts("\nx. Exit the programme\n");
     printf("\nPlease select your option: \n");
     scanf("%c", &choice);     //Reading the menu option entered.

       if(choice == '\n')      //if the choice is the new line character read again.
            scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice)
        {
            case '1': system("cls"); //Clears the screen
                      puts("\nYou have selected to Add packet information, follow on-screen instructions\n"); records = addpacket(&records, info); //calls function "addpacket" and sents a copy of records and pointer to struct info.
                      break;
            case '2': system("cls"); //clears the screen
                      puts("\nAll packet information will now be displayed on the screen\n"); listpackets(records, info);
                      break;
            case '3': system("cls"); //clears the screen
                      puts("\nAll packet information will now be saved\n"); save(records, info);
                      break;
            case '4': system("cls"); //clears the screen
                      puts("\nAll packet information will now be deleted\n");
                      break;
            case 'x': puts("\nThe proframme will now close, Goodbye!\n"); //closes the programme.
                      break;
            default : puts("\nIncorrect option, please select from menu\n"); //used if none of the menu options have been selected.
                      break;
        }
 }while (choice != 'x');    //The programme will run until the "x" option is entered at the menu.
return 0;
}

int addpacket(int *recCount, struct packets *info)
{
int validation = 0;
int stringlength = 0;
int i = 0;
char datatest[50];

do{
        printf("\nPlease enter the source address: \n");
        if (scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].source) == 1)
        {
            validation = 1;
        }
        else{
                validation = 0;
                getchar();
                puts("\nThis is not a valid source address!\n");
            }
    }while (validation != 1);

    printf("\nPlease enter destination address: \n");
    scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].destination); //pointer to the destination address.

printf("\nPlease enter type: \n");
scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].type); // pointer to the address of the type.
printf("\nPlease enter the port: \n");
scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].port); //pointer to the port address.
printf("\nPlease enter data: \n");
scanf("%s", info[*recCount].data); //pointer to the data address.

*recCount ++; //adding one to record count

return *recCount; // returning the record count which will the be copied into records in main.
}

void listpackets(int records, struct packets *info)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i<records; i++){
    printf("\nSource address: %i\n", info[i].source); //Displays the source address.
    printf("\nDestination address: %i\n", info[i].destination);  //Displays the destination address.
    printf("\nType: %i\n", info[i].type); //Displays the type.
    printf("\nPort: %i\n", info[i].port); //displays the port.
    printf("\nData: %s\n", info[i].data); //displays the data information.
}
}

void save(int records, struct packets *info)
{
FILE *savedfile;
char filename[30] = { '\0'}; //this is where the file name will be stored.
int i;

printf("\nPlease enter a filename: \n");
scanf("%s", filename);

if ((savedfile = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("\n%s could not be opened\n", filename);
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    for (i=0; i<records; i++)
        fprintf(savedfile, "%i %i %i %i %s", info[i].source, info[i].destination, info[i].type, info[i].port, info[i].data);
}
fclose(savedfile);
}
```

My save and listpacket function crash when i call them. this was working earlier until i introduced malloc into my programme along side some basic input validation.  i think this could be an issue with pointers.  my programme compiles with no errors/warning so i am stuck with what the problem could be. feel free to try compiling to programme and see what i mean.  any help would be greatly appreciated as i am struggling to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried Debugging your program? This should be the first step.

Comment: well it compiles fine without any errors or warning, that's why im struggling to understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `malloc()` to allocate space for a single `struct packets`. You later treat your `info` pointer as if it is an array of `records` such structures... you're going beyond the boundary of where you have allocated space.

Details on one potential way around (that will auto-grow your array):

```
// change the signature of addpacket():
int addpacket(int *, struct packets **);

...

// change how add packet gets called:
    records = addpacket(&records, &info);

// change addpacket():
int addpacket(int *recCount, struct packets **callerinfo)
{
    ...
    // grow the buffer by one record
    *callerinfo = realloc(*callerinfo, (*recCount + 1) * sizeof (**callerinfo));
    struct packets *info = *callerinfo; // to avoid changing other code
    ... no other changes, just the rest of your routine
}
```

That will come close, of not completely solve it.

The complete program, working for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct packets
{
int source, destination, type, port;
char data[50];
};

int addpacket(int *, struct packets **);
void listpackets(int , struct packets *); 
void save(int, struct packets *);

int main()
{
    struct packets *info;
    char choice;
    int records = 0;

    info = malloc(sizeof(struct packets));

     do
     {
         puts("\n1. Add Packets\n");                //Menu with list of options.
         puts("\n2. List all saved packets\n");
         puts("\n3. Save packets\n");
         puts("\n4. Clear all packet information\n");
         puts("\nx. Exit the programme\n");
         printf("\nPlease select your option: \n");
         scanf("%c", &choice);     //Reading the menu option entered.

         if(choice == '\n')      //if the choice is the new line character read again.
            scanf("%c", &choice);

          switch (choice)
          {
            case '1': system("cls"); //Clears the screen
                      puts("\nYou have selected to Add packet information, follow on-screen instructions\n"); records = addpacket(&records, &info); //calls function "addpacket" and sents a copy of records and pointer to struct info.
                      break;
            case '2': system("cls"); //clears the screen
                      puts("\nAll packet information will now be displayed on the screen\n"); listpackets(records, info);
                      break;
            case '3': system("cls"); //clears the screen
                      puts("\nAll packet information will now be saved\n"); save(records, info);
                      break;
            case '4': system("cls"); //clears the screen
                      puts("\nAll packet information will now be deleted\n");
                      break;
            case 'x': puts("\nThe proframme will now close, Goodbye!\n"); //closes the programme.
                      break;
            default : puts("\nIncorrect option, please select from menu\n"); //used if none of the menu options have been selected.
                      break;
          }
      }while (choice != 'x');    //The programme will run until the "x" option is entered at the menu.
    return 0;
}

int addpacket(int *recCount, struct packets **callerinfo)
{
    int validation = 0;
    int stringlength = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char datatest[50];

    *callerinfo = realloc(*callerinfo, (*recCount + 1) * sizeof (**callerinfo));
    struct packets *info = *callerinfo; // to avoid changing other code

    do{
        printf("\nPlease enter the source address: \n");
        if (scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].source) == 1)
        {
            validation = 1;
        }
        else{
                validation = 0;
                getchar();
                puts("\nThis is not a valid source address!\n");
            }
    }while (validation != 1);

    printf("\nPlease enter destination address: \n");
    scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].destination); //pointer to the destination address.

    printf("\nPlease enter type: \n");
    scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].type); // pointer to the address of the type.
    printf("\nPlease enter the port: \n");
    scanf("%i", &info[*recCount].port); //pointer to the port address.
    printf("\nPlease enter data: \n");
    scanf("%s", info[*recCount].data); //pointer to the data address.

    ++(*recCount); //adding one to record count

    return *recCount; // returning the record count which will the be copied into records in main.
}

void listpackets(int records, struct packets *info)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<records; i++){
        printf("\nSource address: %i\n", info[i].source); //Displays the source address.
        printf("\nDestination address: %i\n", info[i].destination);  //Displays the destination address.
        printf("\nType: %i\n", info[i].type); //Displays the type.
        printf("\nPort: %i\n", info[i].port); //displays the port.
        printf("\nData: %s\n", info[i].data); //displays the data information.
    }
}

void save(int records, struct packets *info)
{
    FILE *savedfile;
    char filename[30] = { '\0'}; //this is where the file name will be stored.
    int i;

    printf("\nPlease enter a filename: \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    if ((savedfile = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%s could not be opened\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<records; i++)
            fprintf(savedfile, "%i %i %i %i %s\n", info[i].source, info[i].destination, info[i].type, info[i].port, info[i].data);
    }
    fclose(savedfile);
}
```

Comment: so how can i get around this issue? i need to use this so it acts instead of an array, this is why i have used the malloc function in the first place. any help you could give id greatly appreciate.

Comment: if _n_ is the number of array elements you will need, `info = malloc(n * sizeof(struct packets));` will do it. Since you don't know in advance the number of records, you could always malloc enough room for some default number of records (perhaps one), and make `realloc()` calls to grow the buffer -- but that could cause performance issues if you have to do it frequently. Also to do that in addpacket() you'll need to pass the address of info so that addpacket() can update main()'s info.

Comment: so just out of curiosity if i was to use the realloc() method of changing this how would i go about it? also can caller be changed to anything or does it have to be left as that?

Comment: this method gives me one error and one warning:
error: too few arguments to function 'realloc'


warning: passing argument 1 of 'realloc' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: plus changing the n in the malloc function to a number still causes the programme to crash when the other functions are called.

Comment: It's not crashing for me. I guess you need to run it in your debugger to determine the point of the crash and go from there.

Comment: Note -- I had a parenthesis in the wrong place on the realloc line in my post; it's fixed now. This caused your warning (and perhaps your crash if you tried running that).

Comment: Note2: I suggest that in your fprintf() for saving the packet data, you include a \n at the end... otherwise your data appears all on a single line.